# setTimeout with canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to run an animate background with canvas.  Right now the `setTimeout` shows an error in chrome `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.  I must be animating it wrong.

When I remove `setTimeout` and just have the `tiles()`, everything works fine (i.e. not animated, but show the correct background that I want).  So I am sure, it has something to do with `setTimeout.`

Anyone got clues for me?

```
function createBackground(){        
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            background = $('#game .background')[0],
            rect = background.getBoundingClientRect(), //returns the dimension of background
            gradient,
            m = monster.settings.monsterSize;

        canvas.width = rect.width;
        canvas.height = rect.height;

        /* create checker */
        tile_cols = canvas.width / m;
        tile_rows = canvas.height / m;

        setTimeout(tiles(ctx, m, tile_cols, tile_rows), 300);

        /* add canvas to html element */
        background.appendChild(canvas); 
    }

    function tiles(ctx, m, tile_cols, tile_rows){
        for (var i=0; i<tile_cols; i++){
            for (var j=0; j<tile_rows; j++){
                var x = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);

                switch(x){
                    case 1:
                        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                        break;

                    ....

                    case 3:
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#00080E';
                        break;  
                }

                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.beginPath(); 
                ...
                ctx.closePath();

                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();

            };
        };      

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Also note you're unnecessarily returning the global object from your function. Since `tiles` is not a constructor and is not being forced into any other context, `this` will merely point to `window`, and thus doesn't need to be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning the result of `tiles(ctx, m, tile_cols, tile_rows)` to the first parameter of `setTimeout`

Change it to

```
setTimeout(function() {
    tiles(ctx, m, tile_cols, tile_rows)
}, 300);
```

You should have a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) for this task. Paul Irish wrote a [good article](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) about it.